$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{a_n\times{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2}}=1$,Proof$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}3na_n^3=1$
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{a_n\times{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2}}=1$,
Proof$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}3na_n^3=1$
I try to use Stolz theorem. This my answer:
It is easy to find $\lim{a_n}=0$. So we just need to prove $\lim{\frac{3}{\frac{1}{a_n^3}-\frac{1}{a_{n-1}^3}}}=1$,according to Stolz theorem.
${\frac{3}{\frac{1}{a_n^3}-\frac{1}{a_{n-1}^3}}}=\frac{3a_n^3a_{n-1}^3}{(a_{n-1}-a_n)(a_n^2+a_na_{n-1}+a_{n-1}^2)}$，
Because $\lim{\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}}=1$,we have $\lim{\frac{3}{\frac{1}{a_n^3}-\frac{1}{a_{n-1}^3}}}=\lim{\frac{a_n^3}{1-\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}}}=\lim{\frac{a_n^3a_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}-a_n}}$，
Let $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2$. So $\lim{a_n}=\lim{\frac{1}{S_n}}$
Then $\lim{\frac{a_n^3a_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}-a_n}}=
\lim{\frac{\frac{1}{S_n^3S_{n-1}^3}}{\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{S_n}}}=\lim{\frac{1}{S_n^2(S_n-S_{n-1})}}=1$
But I can not prove $\lim{a_{n-1}-a_n}=\lim{\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{S_n}}$.
How can I solve it?
What is more ,I wonder is there any different methods?

Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/585358/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2399413/42969– all found with Approach0
